# How can I target other css class in another class?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

So I am making a navbar with react , I use three components for menu bar
text logo and buttons. I give background of navbar to transparent and components to black. When hover components background turn white and navbar to white. The problem is
I used three files for each component and I want to make the components color to turn white when the navbar is hovered , I don't want the components to change color when only it is hovered. How can I do that ?
How can I target the components class Name in the Navbar hover class ?

Answer (score 0):

So, assume that the wrapping element of the navbar is called `emergency-menu-page`, we can simply use the `:hover` selector to change the background of every `div`, `span`, `p` (etc...) inside of `emergency-menu-page`. I use the `!important` property to force an override to existing styles (before the hover). You may not need the `!important` property, depending on how your existing styles are structured.

```
#emergency-menu-page:hover{
  div, span, p{
  background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the component is outside the navbar, you can't achieve your desired goal by using SCSS or CSS (or whatever you use).

I suggest you use Query or JS code to add a specific class to the component once you hover over the navbar.

This class should be implemented in your (CSS/SCSS, ...etc) files so it will add the hover style to your component.